# Best way to make Django's "user" system have "friends"

Tags: django

I am using Django's authorization system to make accounts on my application.

What's the best way at making a "friends" system using the authorization system? I want to be able to link the Users together, but they have to accept the friend request first, and I also want to hold the date they became friends.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An M2M field almost gets you there, but will only store the relationship, not the date it was created. It would be a lot simpler if you can manage without the friendship date.

Otherwise you'll want to create a model something like this:

```
class Friendship(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="friendship_creator_set")
    friend = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="friend_set")
```

You'll want to create a method, probably on the [user profile model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) to make sense of the relationships. Ideally, it should get you something like this:

```
>> User.userprofile.friends()
[{'name': "Joe", 'created': 2010-12-01},]
```

Comment: I have the profile module loaded, and i am storing the extra info in the UserProfile model. I want to link the UserProfile model to this friendship. Can't i use "through" to link them together?

Comment: You don't have to link the UserProfile to the Friendship. You already have the user, so you can query Friendship.objects.filter(Q(creator=user)|Q(friend=user)).all()

Comment: @dotty - You would want to link the "friendship" model to the User model. The UserProfile model will just be a more convenient place to put a friends() method, because it's really difficult to subclass the User model.

Comment: I would like it like User.get_profile().friends.all() to return all friends.

Comment: @dotty I provided the code in a answer, but please don't accept it, as Alan gave the real answer to your problem.

Comment: @dotty Sounds like you'll want a [custom manager](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/custom_managers/) in there. No reason you couldn't handle friend collisions right there as well.

Comment: No one need accept field?

Answer (score 6):

I have done these:

models.py

```
class FriendMgmt(models.Model):
    """
        friends table
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    friend = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="friends")
```

forms.py

```
class FriendMgmtForm(forms.Form):
    """
        Manages friends connections
    """
    friend = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=False)
```

views.py

```
def my_friends(request):
    """
        used for Displaying and managing friends
    """
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = FriendMgmtForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        user = User.objects.get(id=80)
        friend_manage = FriendMgmt(user=request.user, friend= user)
        friend_manage.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/myfriends/')

else:
    form = PdfValidationForm()

user = request.user
profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
full_name = user.get_full_name()
email = user.email
area_interest = profile.area_of_interest
designation = profile.designation
friends = FriendMgmt.objects.filter(user=request.user)


return render_to_response('friends.html',{'form': form,
                                      'full_name':full_name,
                                      'email':email,
                                      'area_interest':area_interest,
                                      'designation':designation,
                                      'friends':friends,

                                      }
                          )
```

url.py

```
 url(r'^myfriends/$',my_friends)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    #other fields

    def get_friends(self):
        user = self.user
        return Friendship.objects.filter(Q(creator=user)|Q(friend=user))


    #then you can call elsewhere

    friends = user.get_profile().get_friends().all()
```

Comment: What would the Friendship look like?

Comment: Friendship would like C. Alan Zoppa answered.

Comment: In this example get_friends method returns Friendship objects, not User objects.